# Is it worth it to buy a 50mm 1.8 lens if my camera has a 1.6 crop factor?

Tags: camera, lenses

I was looking to buy a Canon EF 50mm f/1.8 STM Lens.

But my Canon 7D has a crop factor of 1.6, that would make the 50mm lens look like 80mm. I am a filmmaker, not a photographer, so keeping that in mind, should I still buy it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No one besides you can answer this question.
A Cinema Prime Set pften constists out of a 18mm, 25mm, 35mm, 50mm, 85mm Primes (On Aps-C). It now depends on what you want to shoot. If you mainly shoot interior wides, the lens won't be of much use.

But a 50mm f1.8 is often a great - cheap option to get into blurrier shoots.